# Where condition in linq or lambda query issue

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

This is the inital query.

```
var DevUsers = db.UserProfiles.Include("Tasks").Include("Projects").Include("FollowerTasks").Select(i => new
        {               
            Tasks = db.Tasks.Where(j => j.AssignedToPersonID == i.PersonID).Where(k => k.QAStatus != "Passed").Select(k => new
            {
                k.Projects,
                k.TaskName,
                k.ViewedByDeveloper,
                k.Status,
                k.QAStatus,
                k.ReleaseStatus,
                k.TaskID,
                k.DisplayTaskID,
                k.EstimatedDeliveryDate,
                k.AssignedToPerson.FirstName,
                Tags = k.Tags.Where(p => p.TagType == "General"),
                Modules = k.Tags.Where(p => p.TagType == "Module"),
                CodeTables = db.CodeTables.Where(l => l.Status == k.Status).FirstOrDefault(),
            }).OrderBy(k => k.ViewedByDeveloper).ThenBy(k => k.CodeTables.DisplayOrder).ThenByDescending(k => k.ReleaseStatus),
            i.PersonID,
            i.FirstName,
            i.LastName,
            i.UserID,
            i.EmailAddress,
        }).OrderBy(i => i.FirstName);
```

I cannot do any type of query in this `DevUsers`

```
DevUsers = DevUsers.Where(m=>m.PersonID==1);
```

gives error "cannot convert source..."

how can i apply where conditions. I need to apply where in condition here for `PersonID(int)` and `Status(int)`.

Comment: What type is "PersonID"?

Comment: `OrderBy` return `IOrderedEnumerable`, `Where` - `IEnumerable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `DevUsers` is an `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` and can't be implicitly converted to an `IEnumerable<T>`, so you should define a new variable like this:

```
var newDevUsers =  DevUsers.Where(m=>m.PersonID==1);
```

Or modify your last query using `AsEnumerable()` like this:

```
//...
}).OrderBy(i => i.FirstName).AsEnumerable();
DevUsers = DevUsers.Where(m=>m.PersonID==1);
```

Comment: thank you. but i still cannot search through the Status. `DevUsers = DevUsers.Where(m=>m.Tasks.Status==1);` the `Status` is not identified.

Comment: @remrowruchan what do you mean? looks like that's not your problem described in the question, you should talk more about that.

Comment: i need where condition on `PersonID` (which worked as you said) and also `Status`.

Comment: @remrowruchan what about other properties? (beside `Status`), do you see them in the intellisense popup?

Comment: Oh now i got it... The Tasks is also `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` so need to convert it to `IEnumerable<T>`. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your second question (posted in comment to King King answer) is: m.Tasks is collection (`IOrderedEnumerable<T>` in this case) and doesn't have `Status` property.


If you want all tasks to have given status you should use `DevUsers = DevUsers.Where(m => m.Tasks.All(t => t.Status==1))`.

If you want any task to have given status you should use `DevUsers = DevUsers.Where(m => m.Tasks.Any(t => t.Status==1))`.